# Why can't I access an outer method from an inner method if the outer method has the same name but different signature

Tags: c#

In the following code, why can't I access the outer method InnerMethod(string) from my inner method InnerMethod()?  Afterall, I can access the outer method Test() from the inner method InnerMethod().

```
internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var program = new Program();
            program.OuterMethod();
        }

        public void OuterMethod()
        {
            InnerMethod();
            void InnerMethod()
            {
                Test("hello");  //this is OK
                InnerMethod("hello");  //Error: CS1501 no overload for method 'InnerMethod' takes 1 argument
            }
        }

        public void Test(string text)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
        }

        public void InnerMethod(string text)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"InnerMethod({text})");
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no other `Test` in scope in `OuterMethod`, so the only possible candidate is the one selected for the call. Overload resolution happens in two steps where first the set of candidate methods is determined, and then, from this set, the correct overload is picked. Apparently (and don't make me consult the spec because it's quite involved in this regard) inside a local method non-local methods with the same name are not considered. The argument in favor of this is certainly that it's less brittle -- you can still achieve with you want by explicitly `this.` qualifying the call.